How to change chart's bar colors dynamically for all categories based on values in PowerBI when using legend values also
Is there a way to change bar colors based on values? Specifically trying to make the bar color green when a positive value, and red when negative value for all categories without manually choosing colors when legend is also provided. The only thing I found so far is the ability to change advanced detail label color but not anything else. Ideally, changing the color should support gradient colors. And the function button only becomes available when legend field is not filled in.
The perfect outcome here would be to have the bars be light green when value is lets say 10 and dark green when the value is 1000 and then light red when -10 and dark red when -1000. DOMO does this well in comparison.
One possible solution we could think of is the use of sub report where a chart will be in its own report with preset theme red/green. The only issue here slicing and dicing may not work as expected with other visuals. I also tried some other 3rd party visuals without any luck so far.
Link to file: https://gitlab.com/idevaton/power-bi-dashboards/-/blob/main/Bar%20Colors%20Test/BarColors.pbix



Use the fx icon to provide a measure or set of rules to set the bar colour conditionally. Good guide here: https://blog.coupler.io/power-bi-conditional-formatting/

Hi, yes, that is the solution when only X and Y provided. Please view my improved question with more details. Great blog link btw.

Can you share a link to a .pbix?

Just added link to .pbix in the question description. Thanks

I don't think what you want to do is currently possible. You would have to use Deneb.
